# How to automatically generate text that adopts the same name as an imported image or Excel file in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, batch-processing, illustrator-scripting, javascript, script

I have a lot of product photos to edit in Illustrator.

I want to create several artboards with one product image, and then one text box for each artboard, but I need these to automatically adopt the same name as the image that I've imported.

How can this be achieved? Do I need to script this?

Comment: illustrator has a functionality named ***variable*** please take a look at that; and this is quite a broad question so please tell us what you've tried so far! and about writing script we can help you but we need more details :D

Comment: @DesignPhoenix: I want to create something like this [link](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1KNdzVNTpK1RjSZFMq6zG_VXaT/Core-i3-Laptop-15-6-inch-With-8G-RAM-1TB-Hard-Disk-Gaming-Laptops-Computer-With.jpg). Just a simple product image and has a caption in it. I've tried using variable and tried to import data in csv format but illustrator cc 2019 failed to import it..

Comment: like if you have 100 images you want to create a 100 artboard in single AI file or 100 separate AI with 1 artboard?

Comment: @DesignPhoenix: Yes. i have hundreds of images and want to create in 100 or less artboard in single Ai file but not separate Ai with 1 artboard.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of edits are you planning to do on these photos with Illustrator?

Not sure how useful this is, but InDesign has something called Live Captions that can pull fill names in batch and place these on the page next to the images automatically:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/captions.html
- https://indesignsecrets.com/live-captions-text-variables.php

Comment: I want to create something like this [link](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1KNdzVNTpK1RjSZFMq6zG_VXaT/Core-i3-Laptop-15-6-inch-With-8G-RAM-1TB-Hard-Disk-Gaming-Laptops-Computer-With.jpg). Just a simple product image and has a caption in it.

Comment: You can definitely do that with Live Captions in InDesign.

Comment: @Azli actually lucian is right because inDesign specially made for flyer and poster and etc but have to look that if this can be done in AI script or not!

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Do get back to me if it can be done in ai script.

Comment: @Azli I'm making script for you but it'll take more than i though because illustrator doesn't allow to insert artboard beyond it's bound so for that I have to fix a lot and still not clear about image stuff though. this script will be so big so if possible please use variable or other alternatives!